# Laravel Jetstream Photo Max Size

Tags: laravel, laravel-jetstream

New to PHP and Laravel but fighting through it. I am using Laravel 8 with Jetstream. Now, when Uploading a new Profile-Picture in the Edit-Section of the Frontend, the Frontend only accepts files <1MB.

Checked my PHP.ini and it is set to 100M - so, normally it should work. Any idea, where there might be an additional validation or limitation?

Best
Pierre

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In `app\Actions\Fortify\UpdateUserProfileInformation.php` in the `update()` method there is validation on the size of the image you can upload as the profile picture `'photo' => ['nullable', 'image', 'max:1024']`.

See method below:

```php
public function update($user, array $input)
{
        
    Validator::make($input, [
        'name' => ['required', 'string', 'max:255'],
        'email' => ['required', 'email', 'max:255', Rule::unique('users')->ignore($user->id)],
        'photo' => ['nullable', 'image', 'max:1024'],
    ])->validateWithBag('updateProfileInformation');

    if (isset($input['photo'])) {
        $user->updateProfilePhoto($input['photo']);
    }

    if ($input['email'] !== $user->email &&
        $user instanceof MustVerifyEmail) {
        $this->updateVerifiedUser($user, $input);
    } else {
        $user->forceFill([
            'name' => $input['name'],
            'email' => $input['email'],
            'designation' => $input['designation'],
            'currentemployer' => $input['currentemployer'],
            'employementtype' => $input['employementtype'],
        ])->save();
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks Andrew! Found the same file in the meantime. :-) 

But still, even after changing it, I am unable to upload files >1MB. Buuut, now I am getting "unable to upload" in the frontend. And not "File is to big". So, I need to check, of there is some kind of limitation on another place. 

But thanks!

Comment: @PierrePetite there could be a limit set in the ```.htaccess``` file, unlikely but worth checking. There could be values like this limiting you: 
```php_value upload_max_filesize 10M```
```php_value post_max_size 20M```
```php_value memory_limit 32M```